# Допишите что-то в пустую строчку кода

Tags: python

**задача:**

«Взломайте» guessing_game_2, дописав что-то в пустую строчку. Есть дополнительное условие: в команде, которую вы добавите, не должно быть слова print.

код:

```
import random
# игра-угадайка с планетами
planets = ['Меркурий', 'Венера', 'Земля', 'Марс',
       'Юпитер', 'Сатурн', 'Уран', 'Нептун']
planet = random.choice(planets)
# !!! выше непонятный код !!!
# к этому моменту в переменной planet лежит правильный ответ
warning = 'Присутствует защита от взлома!'
#что НАПИСАТЬ В ЭТОЙ ПУСТОЙ СТРОЧКЕ?
print(warning)
riddle = 'Какую планету я загадал?'
print(riddle)
answer = input()
# далее программа проверяет, что ответ answer совпал с правильным ответом planet
# !!! ниже непонятный код !!!
if answer == 'Плутон':
  print('Плутон уже не считается планетой.')
elif answer not in planets:
  print('Да это же вообще не название планеты Солнечной системы.')
elif answer == planet:
  print('*** Верно! *** Это', answer)
else:
  print('Неверно!')
input()
```

я пытался добавить в пустую строчку, но все равно неправильно :

```
warning = planet + "\n" + warning
```

Comment: Если он непонятный, то очевидно, что нужно дочитать/перечитать учебник.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev вы не по теме что высказываетесь?? непонятный потому что первые уроки и еще такого не проходили и задание совсем в другом

Comment: То есть добавление planet к другому принту не подойдет?

Comment: @VilmirBaikov нет

Comment: мне кажется или строчка кода `print(warning)` появилась несколько позже изначального поста, т.е. была последующей правкой ?

Comment: @Zhihar вам кажется))

Comment: @Андрей, да, действительно кажется, `print(warning)` был

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> оба неправильные) там нужно что то простое без этих функций) мы их еще
> даже не проходили) – Андрей 5 минут назад

кажется я понял, что именно вы проходили (т.е. практически ничего)

поэтому вас должен устроить такой **вариант 3**:

```
warning = 'Присутствует защита от взлома!'
#что НАПИСАТЬ В ЭТОЙ ПУСТОЙ СТРОЧКЕ?
input(planet)
riddle = 'Какую планету я загадал?'
```

Т.е. пользователю изначально будет выведен правильные ответ, затем надо ввести какой-то произвольный текст, а дальше правильный ответ уже

Ведь функцию `input` вы же уже проходили?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**P.S.**

для автоматической проверялки лучше тогда такой взлом:

```
warning = 'Присутствует защита от взлома!'
#что НАПИСАТЬ В ЭТОЙ ПУСТОЙ СТРОЧКЕ?
input(f"*** Верно! *** Это {planet}")
riddle = 'Какую планету я загадал?'
```

Comment: и снова неверно) правильный ответ  warning = planet

Comment: @Андрей, дорогой Андрей, ваше "не верно" меня просто умиляют, начнем с того, что решения верные, т.е. выполняют поставленную задачу (вы не объявляли какие-то другие ограничивающие критерии), а во вторых - я же копировал ВАШ КОД и вставлял в пустое место свой вариант - так вот я что-то в скопированном не наблюдаю `print(warning)`, вы случаем не добавили ее уже потом? и если так- то уж напишите об этом

Comment: не добавил) не пытайтесь свои ошибки оправдать так вот)

Comment: @Андрей, Андрей, а в какой именно строчке у меня ошибка - поясните мне пожалуйста и почему, где в питоновской логике я ошибся?

Answer (score 0):

**вариант 1:** составим свой список планет с блекджеком и ...

```
warning = 'Присутствует защита от взлома!'
#что НАПИСАТЬ В ЭТОЙ ПУСТОЙ СТРОЧКЕ?

planet, planets = "Я", ["Я"]

riddle = 'Какую планету я загадал?'
```

После чего вводить "Я"

**вариант 2:** подменим функцию `input`

```
warning = 'Присутствует защита от взлома!'
#что НАПИСАТЬ В ЭТОЙ ПУСТОЙ СТРОЧКЕ?

def input(): return planets[0]

riddle = 'Какую планету я загадал?'
```

в этом случае даже вводить ничего не требуется - сразу будет выдан правильный ответ

Comment: оба неправильные) там нужно что то простое без этих функций) мы их еще даже не проходили)

Comment: @Андрей, то что вы их не проходили не делает их неправильными ;-) значит надо точнее формулировать задачу

первый вариант вы тоже не проходили? а что вы тогда проходили, чем можно воспользоваться? если и так в обоих вариантах приведена база по сути

Comment: обычными какими нибудь присваиваниями )

Comment: делает это неправильным) неверный ответ пишет, тут как то все попроще делается,чем у вас

Answer (score -1):

Сразу после `answer = input()` нужно добавить `answer = planet`

Что именно вы проходили, если не прошли операцию присваивания.. Вопрос риторический.

Comment: надо написать в пустую строку, а она выше `answer = input()`

Comment: romanr ваше решение неправильное

Comment: А я что фокусник, что бы понять где именно "пустая строчка"???

Comment: Еще и минус вкатил. Наглость не знает придела. Я до сих пор не знаю где твоя мифическая "Пустая строчка", потому что нам ты ее не показал.